# Stored procedure with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to truncate and load a table based on the query I have below. Although, when I try to run it I get the below error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ranked'

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].IM_MTD_avg_bal 
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [Accounts].dbo.IM_MTD_avg_bal;

    INSERT INTO [Accounts].dbo.IM_MTD_avg_bal
    WITH ranked AS 
    (
        SELECT
            IM_ACCT10,
            IM_POST_EYYMD, 
            IM_MTD_AVGBAL,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, IM_POST_EYYMD), 0), [IM_ACCT10]
                              ORDER BY IM_POST_EYYMD ASC) AS rownum
        FROM
            [Accounts].[dbo].[IM_Balances]
    )
    SELECT 
        IM_ACCT10,
        IM_MTD_AVGBAL,
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, IM_POST_EYYMD)) AS Prev_Month ,
        IM_POST_EYYMD
    FROM 
        ranked 
    WHERE
        rownum = 1
        AND IM_POST_EYYMD >= '2023-01-01'`
```

Comment: `WITH foo AS (bah) INSERT INTO x SELECT y FROM foo`

Comment: If you tested the code outside before putting it in a stored procedure, I'm sure you'd have worked it out

Comment: Fyi a `wirh clause ` is more properly known as a common table expression or CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert after selection statement in `cte` expressions. your code modified as below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].IM_MTD_avg_bal 
AS
BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE [Accounts].dbo.IM_MTD_avg_bal;

WITH ranked AS 
(
    SELECT
        IM_ACCT10,
        IM_POST_EYYMD, 
        IM_MTD_AVGBAL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, IM_POST_EYYMD), 0), [IM_ACCT10]
                          ORDER BY IM_POST_EYYMD ASC) AS rownum
    FROM
        [Accounts].[dbo].[IM_Balances]
)
INSERT INTO [Accounts].dbo.IM_MTD_avg_bal
SELECT 
    IM_ACCT10,
    IM_MTD_AVGBAL,
    EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, IM_POST_EYYMD)) AS Prev_Month ,
    IM_POST_EYYMD
FROM 
    ranked 
WHERE
    rownum = 1
    AND IM_POST_EYYMD >= '2023-01-01';
END
```